# Asp.Net Cookie does persists after browser closing

Tags: asp.net, cookies, iis-7, asp.net-4.0

What i'm basically doing is creating a cookie and using form auth.

This is what i'm using to create the cookie.

```
            Session.Add("username", userName);
            Session.Add("password", passWord);

            FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
            string cookiestr;
            HttpCookie ck;
            tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), false, "your custom data");
            cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
            ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
            Response.Cookies.Add(ck);`
```

Because i'm logging in to something secure, what I want to happen is when the browser closes to delete the cookie that this site creates.  However, that doesnt happen, i'm able to log into the secure section of my site.

What am I missing?

basically if I log into /secure/secure.aspx  and then close my browser, i can type in www.myaddress.com/secure/secure.aspx and i'll be logged in.  I'm 100% positive that it will deny the user if the user has never logged in.

Comment: I would examine the actual HTTP headers being sent (e.g. with F12 -> network tab on Chrome). This will let you see what expiration your code is sending on the cookie if any, and what the browser is sending back after you restart it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behavior is controlled by the browser settings.  You can control when the author cookie expires but now when its deleted from the client machine.

One strategy is to set the cookie to expire in X minutes on each request.  That way if the user is inactive on the site for more than X minutes, they will have to login again.

Comment: Jason - then why does my site allow you to still be logged in?

Comment: Jason - the cookie doesnt persist so why does it still allow the login and i'm 100% positive that if you never logged in before you wont be able to log in